# function: return an array containing every word in the string or empty array if string is empty

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, function

I've been tasked with writing a function called "getAllWords".

Given a sentence, "getAllWords" returns an array containing every word in the sentence.

Notes:
* If given an empty string, it should return an empty array.

---

What I've come up with is:

```
function getAllWords(str) {

 var array = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
     array.push(str[i]);
   }
   return array;
   }

   getAllWords('Radagast the Brown');
```

What I get is:

```
  [ 'R','a','d','a','g','a','s','t',' ','t','h','e',' ','B','r','o','w','n']
```

but what I'm trying for is:

```
   ['Radagast', 'the', 'Brown']
```

Comment: try javascript `array.split(" ");`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use the [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method for this purpose:

```
function getAllWords(sentence) {
  return typeof sentence === 'string' && sentence.length > 0 ?
         sentence.split(' ') : [];
}

var words = getAllWords('Radagast the Brown');
```

We then check if the input exists, is actually a string and has any content before returning the **split version** or an **empty array**.

Assuming you will always get a string as input you can further simplify it to:

```
function getAllWords(sentence) {
  return sentence.length > 0 ? sentence.split(' ') : [];
}

var words = getAllWords('Radagast the Brown');
```

Comment: `sentence && typeof sentence === 'string' && sentence.length > 0` is way overkill.

Comment: You are absolutely right about the `sentence && typeof sentence === 'string'` part as it's plain redundant. I would still make sure that the input is a valid string and has content unless we can assume that the input will always be a string. Updated the answer to reflect the change.

Comment: @GorkaHernandez thank you Gorka! your answer worked because it accounted for if the string is empty. :-)

Answer (score -3):

As you can see, iterating over a string will get you each character.

To get each words, you should use `String.split(' ')`

```js
function getAllWords(str) {
  return str.split(' ');
}

console.log(getAllWords('Radagast the Brown'));
```

Comment: @Downvoter, at least a reason for the serial downvote ?

Comment: I'm getting an error message: should return an empty array when given an empty string

Answer (score -3):

```js
var sentence = 'Radagast the Brown';
var words = sentence.split(' ').filter(c => c != '');

document.write(JSON.stringify(words));
```

This is the code you need.

Answer (score -3):

You just need to use the .split() function. This will automatically convert the results into an array:

```
function getAllWords(str) {
    if(str === "") {
        var array = {};
    } else {
        var array = str.split(" ");
    }
    return array;
}
```

EDIT: The function also checks whether the string is empty or not and returns an empty array if the string is empty.

Comment: Why has someone downvoted all the answers on the page for no reason??

Comment: I'm getting an error message: should return an empty array when given an empty string

Comment: @MelvinMullings,  I have adapted the function to check if the string is empty or not and act accordingly.

Comment: thanks! @JeffGugelmann

Answer (score -3):

Use javascripts String `split()` function.

For Example :

```
var str = "Radagast the Brown";
var arr = str.split(' ');
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score -3):

```js
function getAllWords(str) {

 var arr = str.split(" ")
 return arr;
}

  console.log(getAllWords('Radagast the Brown'));
```

Comment: i'm getting the error message: should return an empty array when given an empty string